# I am unable to see the database I created using pgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql

I installed PostgreSQL 11 on Ubuntu 16.04 and pgAdmin4 on Win 10. However I am unable to view the database I created using pgAdmin4 on Ubuntu when I check it using `\l` in `psql`

Comment: You are missing a lot of information, but I would suggest you first check that your pgadmin connection was the same location as psql.

Comment: Yes, the connection is redirected to Ubuntu machine's IP address.i.e. the host ip address is same as Ubuntu's. also getting this:postgres-# \c ABC
FATAL:  database "ABC" does not exist
Previous connection kept

Comment: lowercase `\c abc` would connect to the database, I don't believe it would work for `ABC` however you mentioned that `\l` said it wasn't in the list so it may or may not work. Either way your description is quite limited, perhaps reconnect/refresh pgadmin to check the database is still there...

Comment: Hello Lucas, I tried with every possible way I can but the database itself is not showing up, \l shows the following databases "postgres","sammy","sudo","template0","template1". So, I am not sure why it is not showing ABC. Do I have to rename the db to abc?
"

Comment: Regarding your list, postgres, template0 & template1 are default databases and will be in almost every cluster, `sammy` and `sudo` are yours, does pgadmin show those databases? If `ABC` isn't in the list then I can only assume you are not connected to the same database cluster. Make sure you are connecting to the same ip and port and that the database you created in pgadmin still exists.